# React js - calling a function in render works BUT in componentDidMount doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and have been struggling with this issue for the last 2 days. 
**Why does the call to this.imgList() work when I put it in render (can't be there - performance issues), but doesn't when it's in componentDidMount?**

So I set the state within the constructor:

```
class PersonalBananas extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            username: 0,
            images: 0,
            pred: 0,
            IMAGES: 0
        }
    }
```

Then in componentDidMount I have two ajax calls which work and the call to imgLis() which doesn't:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8081/auth/username')
            .then((response) => {
                let uname = response.data;
                this.setState({
                    username: uname
                });
            })

        axios.get('http://localhost:8081/auth/files')
            .then((response) => {
                let imgs = response.data;
                console.log("images response: "+imgs);
                this.setState({
                    images: imgs
                });
            })

        this.imgList();
    }
```

This method I call from my imgLis(), there are some ajax calls:

```
    getImgPred = (path) => {
        var username = this.state.username;
        var $this = this;

        let regex = new RegExp(username+'\/(.*?)$');
        let imgRegex= /{username}\/(.*?)$/;

        let filename = regex.exec(path);
        console.log("filename at front:"+filename[1]);
        console.log("regex1:"+imgRegex+", regex2:"+regex);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8081/auth/imgpred',
            "filename=" + filename[1]
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log("response at front (get img prediction):"+response.data);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                $this.setState({
                    pred: response.data
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Then there is this infamous imgLis(), which works like a charm when I call it directly from render, but now doesn't:

```
    imgList = () => {
        var $this = this;
        const IMAGES = [];
        const imgpaths = this.state.images;

        for (let i = 0; i < imgpaths.length; i++) {
            var path = imgpaths[i]
            this.getImgPred(path);
            console.log("pred:"+$this.state.pred);

            IMAGES.push({
                src: process.env.PUBLIC_URL +`/${path}`,
                thumbnail: process.env.PUBLIC_URL +`/${path}`,
                thumbnailWidth: 320,
                thumbnailHeight: 320,
                caption: $this.state.pred
            })
        }
        this.setState({
            IMAGES: IMAGES
        })
    };
```

And in my render() I try to get the IMAGES -doesn't work, BUT it works when I replace {this.state.IMAGES} with {this.imgLis()} and in imgLis() just return IMAGES...

```
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Gallery images={this.state.IMAGES}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PersonalBananas;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `componentDidMount`, use a callback function after `this.setState` like so:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8081/auth/files')
.then((response) => {
    let imgs = response.data;
    console.log("images response: "+imgs);
    this.setState({
      images: imgs
    }, () => {
      this.imgList();
    });
})
```

The reason being that `this.imgList()` uses `this.state.images`, but `this.setState()` is not synchronous in React. Since `render()` is called after every `this.setState()` your function worked there, because `this.state.images` is defined but not in `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount() run once, but you have async API calls (axios) inside it. When this.imgList() is called in componentDidMount(), most probably you had not get your response back yet.

Simple fix is

```js
axios('http://localhost:8081/auth/files')
  .then((response) => {

    let imgs = response.data;
    console.log("images response: "+imgs);
    this.setState(
      {images: imgs},
      this.imgList // Will run after setState is completed
    );
  })
```

Comment: Doesn't work like this, you have to add a callback func: this.setState(
      {images: imgs},
      function() { this.imgList } );                       thanks :)

Comment: this.setState({..}, () => { this.imgList() } or this.setState({...}, function() { this.imgList() } or this.setState({...}, this.imgList) are equivalent